# How to dismiss the eventeditviewcontroller when I have allowed editing on eventviewcontroller?

Tags: ios, objective-c, viewcontroller, dismiss, ekevent

So I present an EKEventViewController with a UINavigationController.  From inside the EKEventViewController I am able to edit the event.  It presents an EKEventEditViewController.  Everything thing works great(cancel/done buttons) except when I delete the event inside the EKEventEditViewController I recieve this

attempt to dismiss modal view controller whose view does not currently appear. self =  modalViewController =

Here is my code...

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [CalendarViewController connectExchange];

    if (connectionEx == YES)
    {
        NSDate *dateRepresentingThisDay = [self.sortedDays objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
        NSArray *eventsOnThisDay = [self.sections objectForKey:dateRepresentingThisDay];
        EKEventViewController *eventViewController = [[EKEventViewController alloc] init];

        eventViewController.allowsEditing = YES;
        eventViewController.delegate = self;
        EKEvent *event = [eventsOnThisDay objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        eventViewController.event = event;

        UINavigationController *navBar = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:eventViewController];

        [self.navigationController presentViewController:navBar animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
}

- (void)eventViewController:(EKEventViewController *)controller didCompleteWithAction:(EKEventViewAction)action
{
    EKEvent *event = controller.event;

    CalendarViewController * __weak weakSelf = self;
    // Dismiss the modal view controller
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^
    {
        if (action == EKEventViewActionDone)
        {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
               NSError *err;
               [self.eventStore saveEvent:event span:EKSpanThisEvent error:&err];
               [self updateEvent:event];
            });
        }
        if (action == EKEventViewActionDeleted)
        {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
               [self deleteEvent:event];
               NSError *error;
               EKEvent *eventRemove = [self.eventStore eventWithIdentifier:event.eventIdentifier];
               [self.eventStore removeEvent:eventRemove span:EKSpanThisEvent error:&error];
            });
        }
        if (action == EKEventViewActionResponded)
        {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            });
        }

     weakSelf.eventsList = [self fetchEvents];
     [weakSelf.tableView reloadData];
     NSLog(@"Event Updated");
     }];
}
```

How am I suppose to properly dismiss the ViewControllers after deleting the event via the EKEventEditViewController?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem by subclassing EKEventViewController and setting up EKEventEditViewDelegate and EKEventViewDelegate.

Here is my changed didSelectRow(CalendarViewController.m),

```
    EditViewController *eventViewController = [[EditViewController alloc] init];

    eventViewController.allowsEditing = YES;
    eventViewController.delegate = self;
    EKEvent *event = [eventsOnThisDay objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    eventViewController.event = event;

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:eventViewController animated:YES];
    self.editingEvent = eventViewController.event;
```

The EditViewController is my subclass of EKEventViewController.

In the subclass(EditViewController.m) I added my own edit button with a selector in viewDidLoad,

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UIBarButtonItem *editItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemEdit target:self.delegate action:@selector(editCalEvent)];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = editItem;
}
```

Now back in CalendarViewController.m after adding the EKEventEditViewDelegate and EKEventViewDelegate to the @interface I added new methods

```
- (void)editCalEvent
{

     EKEventEditViewController *editController = [[EKEventEditViewController alloc] init];

     editController.event = self.editingEvent;
     editController.eventStore = self.eventStore;
     editController.editViewDelegate = self;

     [self presentViewController:editController animated:YES completion:nil];

}

- (void)eventEditViewController:(EKEventEditViewController *)controller didCompleteWithAction (EKEventEditViewAction)action
{
     EKEvent *thisEvent = controller.event;

     [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:^
     {
         switch (action)
         {
             {case EKEventEditViewActionCanceled:
                //NSLog(@"Canceled action");
                break;}

             {case EKEventEditViewActionSaved:
                [self.eventStore saveEvent:thisEvent span:EKSpanThisEvent error:nil];
                [self updateEvent:thisEvent];
                break;}
             {case EKEventEditViewActionDeleted:
                [self deleteEvent:thisEvent];
                NSError *error;
                EKEvent *eventRemove = [self.eventStore eventWithIdentifier:thisEvent.eventIdentifier];
                [self.eventStore removeEvent:eventRemove span:EKSpanThisEvent error:&error];
                //NSLog(@"Deleted action");
                break;}
             {default:
                break;}
         }
     }];
}

- (void)eventViewController:(EKEventViewController *)controller didCompleteWithAction:(EKEventViewAction)action
{

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `editViewDelegate` instead of `delegate`.